# How to spam my server as a malicious IP for testing?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application that I've built a feature around that blocks malicous IPs. I'd like to test this out by spamming my application from a malicious IP. Are there any capabilities of Node.JS/Express Service packages that are capable of this?

Comment: What about ye-olde `ab`?

Comment: You should check out `ab` or [hey](https://github.com/rakyll/hey), a modern replacement for `ab`.

Comment: Does ab or hey allow me to mask my IP?